# LLVM API pointer type support

Tags: c, pointers, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am trying to build a null pointer using LLVM build store instruction builder for the following piece of code:

```
int *x;
x = 0;
```

The problem that I am facing is that when assigning zero to x I am getting an incompatible type error as 0 is of i32 type and x is of i32** type.
I am using LLVMPointerType to create a pointer type for zero and using it in the BuildStore builder but LLVMPointerType returns an LLVMTypeRef whereas BuildStore needs LLVMValueRef Type of argument.
I am stuck not being able to type cast and could really use some help.

Also is there another way of creating a NULL pointer in LLVM?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after creating a null pointer, you're almost there -- you have a reference to the type that you want (`i32*` in this case), and now you have to create a constant of that type. In this case you can use the [`LLVMConstPointerNull`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMCCoreValueConstant.html#ga682a6624ba9e6d0cf30c792a4d87bba7) function to get a value representing a null pointer of a given type.

More generally, if you're starting with an integer value and want to cast it to a pointer value, you can create an `inttoptr` constexpr or instruction using [`LLVMBuildIntToPtr`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMCCoreInstructionBuilder.html#gaa95432528a09d5bd7b018145c5cd7897).

Comment: I was trying to use LLVMBuildIntToPtr before but it is showing me an error of arguments of incompatible type, I am using                                                 $$ = LLVMBuildIntToPtr(Builder,$3,LLVMTypeOf($1),"");                         but it throwing me an error and even with                                                     $$ = LLVMBuildStore(Builder,LLVMConstPointerNull((LLVMPointerType(LLVMTypeOf($3)),0)),$1);                                        it is throwing me an error. @IsmailBadawi

Comment: @ManishKhilnani Please include the code you're using and the specific errors you're getting in the question.

Comment: $$ = LLVMBuildStore(Builder,(LLVMConstPointerNull(LLVMInt32TypeInContext(Context))),$1);                and this is the error that I am getting::typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type llvm::cast(Y*) [with X = llvm::PointerType; Y = llvm::Type; typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type = llvm::PointerType*]: Assertion `isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"' failed. @Ismail Badawi

Comment: @ManishKhilnani You need to pass a pointer type to `LLVMConstPointerNull`. In the question you mentioned you were using `LLVMPointerType` to get a pointer type.

Comment: Thank you..I was able to figure that out!!